# How do I wrap part of object around cylinder?

Tags: modifiers

I want to wrap the top part of the banner (red) onto the horizontal cylinder of the pole and then use the wind physics for the rest of the banner. How I can wrap only the top part? I have divided the surface but shrinkwrap does not gives me the result I need. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Have you tried shrinkwrap using a vertex group applied to the top of the flag?

Comment: You'll need to subdivide the top part horizontally. A few loop cuts or knife cuts in edit mode should do the trick. A mesh can only bend as much as its geometry allows it to. You can also use the spin tool

Comment: Hello could you please make a drawing of how it is supposed to wrap onto the cylinder?

Comment: ![Banner help](https://imgur.com/pdDnsgW)

Comment: The easiest way if you make loop cuts on the rod, duplicate tha part where the flag is,  upscale them, delete the face near the flag and bridge them together.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a simple deform modifier, if you have this topology (create some loop cuts):

[image]

and assign the selected vertices to a group:

[image]

and use the simple deform modifier like this:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I did manage to end to this solution by myself. I did not used the correct start for the loop initially.

Comment: @Morfeas333: If my answer helped you, pls click on the checkmark left of my answer. thx.